# Tornado, run coroutine method with arguments from synchronous code

Tags: asynchronous, arguments, tornado, coroutine

According to a few examples online, in order to run asynchronous methods decorated with tornado.gen.coroutine from synchronous code, you can use following:

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def do_something():
   do_something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().run_sync(do_something)
```

However if you have arguments to coroutine method, is there a way to run it?

Answer (score 9):

Yes:

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def do_something(arg):
   do_something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().run_sync(lambda: do_something(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using partial:

```
import functools
import tornado.gen

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def do_something(arg):
   do_something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().run_sync(
         functools.partial(do_something, 1))
```